# Protcol Buffers - Python - Issue with tutorial

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

**Context**

- I'm working through this tutorial:
  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial
- I've created files by copy and pasting from the above tutorial

**Issue**

When I run the below file in `python launcher`nothing happens:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import addressbook_pb2
import sys

# Iterates though all people in the AddressBook and prints info about them.
def ListPeople(address_book):
  for person in address_book.person:
    print "Person ID:", person.id
    print "  Name:", person.name
    if person.HasField('email'):
      print "  E-mail address:", person.email

    for phone_number in person.phone:
      if phone_number.type == addressbook_pb2.Person.MOBILE:
        print "  Mobile phone #: ",
      elif phone_number.type == addressbook_pb2.Person.HOME:
        print "  Home phone #: ",
      elif phone_number.type == addressbook_pb2.Person.WORK:
        print "  Work phone #: ",
      print phone_number.number

# Main procedure:  Reads the entire address book from a file and prints all
#   the information inside.
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
  print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE"
  sys.exit(-1)

address_book = addressbook_pb2.AddressBook()

# Read the existing address book.
f = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
address_book.ParseFromString(f.read())
f.close()

ListPeople(address_book)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question**

- What steps should I take to work out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's not "nothing happens". You got an error message showing that you didn't call the program correctly. Specifically, you didn't pass it an address book file to use.

Comment: Where does the code find the address book? And what extension should it end in?

Comment: It gets the path to the address book as a command line argument. The extension doesn't matter.

Comment: It never gives me a chance to enter the path in the terminal

Comment: Yes it does. Specifically, your chance came when you entered that big `cd blah && '/usr/bin/python' '/Users...test.py' && ...` command. Why did you use that command, rather than one that would provide an argument to the program? Why did you use `'/usr/bin/python'` rather than just `python`? Why are all the paths quoted? Do you even know what that line does?

Comment: I didn't type that, I'm dragging the .py file to the python launcher icon on my dock.

Comment: Learn how to use the shell, then. The knowledge you need is far beyond the scope of this answer, but I can start you off by saying that the command should be `python test.py whatever_you_called_the_address_book_file`.

Comment: cool that worked, thank you for your help. Getting a new a error, but its related to protobufs I believe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36146/discussion-between-drc-and-user2357112)